# How to ensure link is disabled by default when the page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have twp problems

Mark up for the link

```
                <a href="/Home/DisplaySpreadSheetData" id="displaySpreadSheetLink">DisplaySpreadsheetData</a>
```

1)
Under document.ready i have this line of code to make sure the link is disabled by default but it does not work.

```
        $('#displaySpreadSheetLink').bind('click', disableLink);
```

Code to disable the link

```
    var disableLink = function (e) {       
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;      
    }
```

2) 
when the link is clicked i want to  make sure that if checkFile() returns true the link should be disabled

```
    $('#displaySpreadSheetLink').click(function (e) {
        if (checkFile()) {          
        e.preventDefault();
    }      
});
```

There are two problems here. How can i correct the first problem and for the second one i think e.preventDefault() does not get executed even if checkFile() returns true. 
Can anyone help please?

Comment: What is your Error msg?

Comment: You have two click events bound to your link; the `disableLink` and the second with `checkFile()` in it. You shouldn't need the first one at all, do you? When do you bind the second event, inside or outside of document-ready?

Comment: @ Lilith2k3 THere is no error message the link takes the user to the other page even if i try to disable it by default.  @Cory the binding happens inside document-ready(). I was just trying to see which of the click events work.

Comment: Can you post the markup for your link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have an issue because you've actually bound *two* click events to your link. You should unbind the `disableLink` function before you bind the new functionality:

```
function disableLink(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // don't use return false here.
}

$(function() {
    $('#displaySpreadSheetLink').click(disableLink);
});

// later on

$('#displaySpreadSheetLink').unbind('click').click(function (e) {
    if (checkFile()) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }      
});
```

Also, double-check your logic for `checkFile()`. Just based on the name I would assume, having never seen your code before, that you'd want to prevent the default behavior if `checkFile()` *fails*. Are you sure you don't want `if (!checkFile()) { ... }`?

Another approach might be to deal with only a single event, but take into account some extra state information as to whether the default behavior should execute or not:

```
(function($) {
    var loaded = false;
    $('#displaySpreadSheetLink').click(function(e) {
        if (!loaded || checkFile()) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
    $(function() {
        loaded = true;
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Nailed it Cory :) Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disabling a link with a function after the page loads, you should change the HTML to be disabled initially by using a `<span>` with a CSS class that looks like a disabled link.

Instead of calling `checkFile()` every time the user clicks the link, have code in the sections that can alter whether `checkFile()` is `true` or `false`. For example, if `checkFile()` becomes `true` after a file is uploaded, put code in the file upload function to enable the link by replacing the `<span>` with an `<a>`, and link-disabling code in the appropriate places where `checkFile()` might become `false` again.

Merely using `preventDefault()` will make the link look clickable, which is probably bad UI design if it actually does nothing.

Comment: Will Look into the CSS way later Corion. THank you for your advice

Comment: Not sure if you had already planned on doing this, but if you stick with the bound function you should at least alter the CSS class of the link. You can make it so it looks disabled and no longer uses the default `pointer` cursor. Additionally, you should also change the alt/hover text to indicate why the link can't be clicked.